# move constructor/assignment of std::unique_ptr: memory reallocation?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, move-semantics

In using move constructor/assignment of `std::unique_ptr`, can one assume that the underlying object is not reallocated in memory, such that a raw pointer to it remains valid?

Consider the following program:

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct A {
    std::unique_ptr<T> data = nullptr;
    T *p;
    template <class... U>
    A(U&&... x) : data{std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<U>(x)...)}, p{data.get()} { }
};

int main()
{
    A<int> v{2};
    std::cout << std::hex << v.p << std::endl;
    A<int> w{std::move(v)};
    std::cout << w.p << std::endl;
}
```

Here `w` is constructed with the default move constructor of `A`, which calls the move constructor of `std::unique_ptr`.

It appears by the output that the underlying allocated `int` is not really moved in memory, so the default move constructor correctly initialized `w.p` as identical to `v.p`.
Trying with other types for `T` gives analog result.

Can one assume that the move constructor of `std::unique_ptr` does not really move the object in memory, so that in the above program the default move constructor is correct?
Is that specified by the language?

Or to avoid a dangling pointer must one add a move constructor explicitly like the following?

```
A(A<T>&& other) : data{std::move(other.data)}, p{data.get()} { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the standard, [[unique.ptr.single.ctor]/20](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/unique.ptr.single.ctor#20)

> ```
> unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& u) noexcept;
> ```
>
> Postconditions: get() yields the value u.get() yielded before the construction. u.get() == nullptr.

No memory allocation happens in move construction; after `A<int> w{std::move(v)};`, `w.data.get()` (and `w.p`) would be the same as `v.data.get()` before, i.e. `v.p`.

And the move constructor of `std::unique_ptr` is marked as `noexcept`, which also implies that no memory allocation here.

IMO even the implicitly-generated move constructor works fine here, adding a user-defined one is better, especially you can set the raw pointer `p` to `nullptr` in the moved object (for consistency).

```
A(A<T>&& other) : data{std::move(other.data)}, p{data.get()} { other.p = nullptr; }
```

Comment: or `p(std::exchange(other.p, nullptr))`